# Where to add css file that I want my forms to use?

Tags: forms

Where and how should I add the css file that I want my forms to use?

Thank you!

Comment: add styles in main stylesheet "style.css" in theme directory

Comment: @Anjum thank you - is it usually done manually? Or through some wordpress cms setting?

Comment: just copy css styles and paste in the bottom of style.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`wp_enqueue_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) to add additional stylesheets to a theme. Additionally, you can use it with a [Child Theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) to preserve your edits in case the original theme is updated.

```
function wpa_form_style() { 
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'my-form-styles', 
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/my-form-styles.css'
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpa_form_style' );
```

or if you only need your styles for a specific page, conditionally enqueue it with a check for `is_page()`:

```
function wpa_form_style() {
    if( is_page( 'contact' ) ){
        wp_enqueue_style(
            'my-form-styles', 
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/my-form-styles.css'
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpa_form_style' );
```